# Planning to make web app like Canva

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to make app like canva but i dont know where to start, i have good experience in html and css but a basic javascript.

I need to know what they use.

- How to save html data to image like canva functions.
- How they save the data and load it again.

I already try Html2canvas but problem in images limit.

Comment: Provide what have you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Javascript canvas libraries like [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/)
but i don't think that basic knowledge of javascript would be enough for such app you will have to improve your javascript skills to an at least intermediate level.

Comment: But fabric js is based on canvas and canva using pure HTML. I have the same issue, how canva work with HTML. because canvas no longer enables to support of large size, it cause an issue of hang.